# How to design table to quickly query by username or handle?

Tags: database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to build a platform where user profiles can be viewed publicly and user can edit own profile, like GitHub or LinkedIn! For authentication I want to use AWS Cognito and AWS DynamoDB to save data like `handle` and `username`.

How to design a table to quickly query by `username` (included in the JWT-token) or `handle`? I had in mind setting `pk: USER#{username}`, `handle: HANDLE#{handle}`, GSI where `pk: HANDLE#{handle}` and `username: USER#{username}`.

Answer (score 1):

That design works fine, given the two access patterns you've explained. If you have more that might impact the design.

Be aware the GSI is eventually consistent so will update some time after the base table write, usually some fraction of a second.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! An additional question on this. Given that `user` has many more attributes per item – do you think it makes sense to have the GSI only on `handle` and `username` (to occupy less space) and basically have a query to get from `handle` -> `username`. then another query with `pk: username`.
OR
To have the GSI on all attributes and just query once. Considering both cost / performance.

Comment: Probably you'll want to project all the attributes, assuming you have < 1 KB of data in the item. The write costs will be the same. You'll spend a tiny bit extra on storage, but you'll skip paying for (and waiting for) that second read. The larger your item, the more worthwhile it is to save on writes/storage by keeping a single copy paying for that second read.